# Assign value to coins for score calculation

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am developing a microgame to understand the basics of Unity.
There will be a player like "Super Mario" who collects different types of coins such as gold and silver. Now, I am trying to calculate the score. Assume that a gold coin will be 2 points, a silver coin will be 1 point. What is the best practice of assigning values to coins and finding the value of a coin when updating the score?

I checked the Is Trigger property of coins. And using the following script to update the score.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.layer == 9)
    {
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
    }
}
```

The name of the 9th layer is "Coin". All coins have the same layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this could work:

```cs
public player : monoBehaviour
{

public int coins = 0;

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.layer == 9)
    {
        var coinComponent = other.GetComponent<CoinComponent>();
        if(coinComponent == null) throw new Exception($"{other.gameObject.Name} had no coinComponent! ")  

        this.coins += coinComponent.value;

        Destroy(other.gameObject);        
    }
}
}
```

```cs
public CoinComponent : Monobehaviour
{
    // Set this from the editor
    public int value = 1; // or 2 or 3 or 213213
}
```

Untested, just to show the principle.

coinComponent would also be a great candidate for using scriptableObjects - although i gues you try this first.

Here's a quick video on scriptable objects.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lJxy3oTZeCs

Also the unity docs are quite good in general, so heres the one for scriptable objects:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptableObject.html

In your sample, you'd make something like this:

```cs
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "myCoin", menuName = "ScriptableObjects/Coin", order = 1)]
public CoinComponent : ScriptableObject
{
    public int value = 0;

    // Could add a check to make sure you did change the value, depends on your own preference. I add checks everywhere ;)
    private void OnEnable()
   {
       if(value = 0) throw new Exception($"Did not set value for {this.Name}"); // Idk if 'name exists' but i assume it does.
   }

}
```

And then you'd create 2 scriptable objects, one for gold and set the value to 2 and one for silver and set it to 1.

Answer (score 1):

I would use tags instead of layers, I would simply assign goldCoins tag to gold coins and same for silver coins and update the score whenever the tags gets triggered.

```
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
     if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Custom Tag")) 
    
   // do things ;)
    
    }
```